# Is Nest JS Microservice really a microservice?

Tags: node.js, nestjs, microservices, monorepo, nestjs-microservice

I was wondering if we can build microservices application using Nest JS with separate repositories. All of the docs in Nest JS regarding microservices only support monorepo style and single database.

I tried finding sources regarding Nest JS Microservices but all of them are monorepo and single database.

Comment: Yes, you can build "micro" apps with [NestJS](https://nestjs.com/). I build [this repo](https://github.com/msrumon/microservice-architecture) as a reference for myself way back.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Monorepos are just a *preference* of an approach. Nothing says all of the NestJS microservices you create, which would be independently ran processes, have to be within the same repo. By the time you're running your services in production, it won't matter what repo they came from, just the configuration they use to connect to the broker/each other